# Meaning of the backtick character in Python

Tags: python

I'm just getting started with python. Can somebody interpret line 2 of the following code snippet?  I don't understand the `` `num` `` bit. I tried to replace the backtick character with a single tick `'`, but then it broke. Just a detailed explanation of that line would be great.

```
loop_count = 1000000
irn = ''.join([`num` for num in range(loop_count)])
number = int(irn[1]) * int(irn[10]) * int(irn[100]) * int(irn[1000]) * int(irn[10000]) * int(irn[100000]) * int(irn[1000000])
print number
```

Comment: the `` turns it into a string. without it, you get an array of ints, not an array of strings

Comment: its equivalent to `str(num)`, I think

Comment: @Jeff but why is it ` and not '?  I tried to replace ` with ' and it broke, as it did when I replaced it with "

Comment: Join: 'a'.join(['b','c'] -> 'bac'

Comment: Out of curiosity - was someone trying to solve an Euler problem?

Comment: See [5.2.9. String conversions](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html?highlight=expressions#string-conversions) in the documentation. They're also called reverse or backward quotes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Backticks are a deprecated alias for the `repr()` builtin function, so the second line is equivalent to the following:

```
irn = ''.join([repr(num) for num in range(loop_count)])
```

This uses a list comprehension to create a list of strings representing numbers, and then uses `''.join()` to combine that list of strings into a single string, so this is equivalent to the following:

```
irn = ''
for num in range(loop_count):
    irn += repr(num)
```

Note that I used `repr()` here to be consistent with the backticks, but you will usually see `str(num)` to get the string representation of an int (they happen to be equivalent).

Comment: Where/when were/are they deprecated?

Comment: Backticks are a SyntaxError in Python 3, not sure exactly when it was decided to remove them, but 2.7 is the last Python version that allows them.

Comment: I asked because there was no mention of it being deprecated in the 2.6 & 2.7 documentation. In the **Removed Syntax** section of [_What's New In Python 3.0_](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html) it says "Removed backticks (use `repr()` instead)", which I suppose could be called the ultimate act of disapproval...

Answer (score 2):

1. `for num in range(loop_count)` iterates over all numbers from zero up to and excluding 1,000,000
2. `num` in backticks converts each number to string using the [`repr()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) function.
3. `''.join(...)` merges all those strings into one without any separators between them.
4. `irn = ...` stores the result in `irn`.

Comment: So it is the same as doing str(num)?

Comment: In this case, yes.  `repr` and `str` have slightly different purposes, and can produce different text depending on the type.